# How can I use a private method in MapKit on iOS?

Tags: ios, mapkit, iphone-privateapi

This is purely for a personal app that I will not be submitting to the app store. I would like to use a method and/or property that is in a private header file within the MapKit.framework. What is the process for using such a private method/property? What are the steps to take in Xcode? Thank you.

Comment: Hard to see what the question is here. If it's private, how do you know what it is? Or, if you know what it is, what's stopping you from just using it?

Comment: Expose the private method or property, e.g., `@interface MKMapView () (UIView *)_contentView; @end`.  Now you can call it normally without seeing an undeclared selector error.

Comment: Thank you, both. Do you know the way to expose the private method/property in Swift?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know how to write the declaration in Swift.